# How to create a Psychtoolbox sound schedule in which white noise plays in the background?

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

I have a 10-minute wav file for white noise that I want to play continuously in the background while a 100ms tone-beeping sound wav file plays at random intervals between 1-9s. How do I create a sound schedule for this with psychtoolbox functions in matlab?

Answer (score 0):

You can create 'slave' audio devices. Each one can then operate independently and the master device takes care of combining them, see:
http://psychtoolbox.org/docs/PsychPortAudio-OpenSlave

-iftach